# Why isn't my pack() packing my data?

Tags: perl

What I am trying to do is simple. Here below.

```
my @arr = split(/\s+/,"50 00 9F 11 00 28 82 48 21 84 BC 00 01 02 01 00 09 01 38 00 23 05 08 01 01 02 00 00 18 00 50 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 0C FE CE 00 0F 00 FD FF 2D 00 00 00 00 00 04 01 0C FE");
my @hexData;
my $i=0;
foreach my $elem(@arr){
    $hexData[$i]=hex($elem);
    $i++;
}
my $data= pack ('C', @hexData);
print $data;
```

And its not working :( Would you please help?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell everyone in what way it is not working?

Comment: "So, what's wrong with your car?" "It's not working!" // "So, how are you feeling today?" "I'm not working!" // "What seems to be the problem?" "My computer is not working!" // Nope, that phrase does not work at the garage, the doctor's office or the computer support. Wonder why people think it will work on StackOverflow.

Comment: I should have used ('C*', @hexdata) as TLP said.

Comment: `my @arr = split(/\s+/,"50 00 9F ... 0C FE");` is better written as `my @arr = qw"50 00 9F ... 0C FE";`.

Answer (score 8):

TLP's solution is quite right, but `pack` actually has the ability to deal with hex.

```
my $data = "50 00 9F 11 00 28 82 48 21 84 BC 00 01 02 01 00 09 01 38 00 23 05 08 01 01 02 00 00 18 00 50 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 0C FE CE 00 0F 00 FD FF 2D 00 00 00 00 00 04 01 0C FE";
$data =~ tr/ //d; # Remove the spaces
print pack "H*", $data;
```

does the whole thing without the intermediate array.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not terribly familiar with the `pack` function, but it seems to me that your template expects only one value.

Perhaps you should try

```
my $data = pack ('C*', @hexData);
```

And while you are at it, upgrade your code to something more perlish:

```
my @arr = qw(50 00 9F 11 00 28 82 48 21 84 BC 00 01 02 01 00 09 01 38 00 23 05 
             08 01 01 02 00 00 18 00 50 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 0C FE 
             CE 00 0F 00 FD FF 2D 00 00 00 00 00 04 01 0C FE);
my @hexData;

foreach my $elem (@arr) {
    push @hexData, hex($elem);
}

my $data = pack ('C*', @hexData);
print $data;
```

Or even:

```
my $data = pack("C*", map(hex, @arr));
```

Comment: Thanks #TLP. I get -1 instead of the timestamp :(. Here is the code : http://nopaste.dk/p4694

Comment: @Fighter2 If this does not fix your problem, you should ask a follow up question.

Comment: It certainly did solve my problem and I am grateful for you. I am thankful. I just thought you'd have more room for grace in your heart to look at that code I wrote and help me why I don't get the timestamp and get the 'else' and not go into my 'if' condition. I spend all my day on it. What takes me a day, only might take you minutes. Not everyone are verbose in Perl.

Comment: @Fighter2 I'd be happy to help you with any specific questions you have, but you'll have to do your own debugging. It's not a small thing you are asking, compared to changing `C` to `C*`.

Comment: @Fighter2: As TLP wrote, accept one of the posted answers to this question, then post a new one addressing your next problem. That might also improve your chances at getting a quick reply, as TLP might not be around all day to answer.